# Consumindo webservice do Protheus em C# (array)

Tags: c#, web-service

Tenho dois webservices desenvolvidos no Protheus(TOTVS) que serão consumidos em minha aplicação em C# no VS2013(Windows form).

O primeiro sempre retorna uma string e está funcionando perfeitamente, já o segundo retorna um array e esse eu não consigo consumir de jeito nenhum.

Não é conexão, porque se eu alterar o retorno do segundo webservice para uma string tudo funciona normalmente, porém como array não consigo fazer o Visual Studio 2013 entender nem a pau.

Ele fica me retornando um erro de "Cannot implicitly convert type" e nada resolve.

Segue o método do webservice publicado e o erro gerado:

WEBSERVICE REQUEST:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?"
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
   <_CFILIAL>STRING</_CFILIAL>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

WEBSERVICE RESPONSE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?"
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
   <TARRAY>
      <TESTEARRAY>
         <_CCONTIGENCIA>STRING</_CCONTIGENCIA>
         <_CDIGITAL01>STRING</_CDIGITAL01>
         <_CDIGITAL02>STRING</_CDIGITAL02>
         <_CMATRICULA>STRING</_CMATRICULA>
         <_CNOME>STRING</_CNOME>
         <_CSITUACAO>STRING</_CSITUACAO>
      </TESTEARRAY>
      <TESTEARRAY>
         <_CCONTIGENCIA>STRING</_CCONTIGENCIA>
         <_CDIGITAL01>STRING</_CDIGITAL01>
         <_CDIGITAL02>STRING</_CDIGITAL02>
         <_CMATRICULA>STRING</_CMATRICULA>
         <_CNOME>STRING</_CNOME>
         <_CSITUACAO>STRING</_CSITUACAO>
      </TESTEARRAY>
   </TARRAY>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

CONSUMINDO:

```
WS_FUNCSPONTO.FUNCSPONTO Recebe_Cadastro = new WS_FUNCSPONTO.FUNCSPONTO();
WS_FUNCSPONTO.TESTEARRAY qwert = new WS_FUNCSPONTO.TESTEARRAY();
qwert = Recebe_Cadastro.PEGAINFORM("00");
```

ERRO:
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'Relogio_Ponto.WS_FUNCSPONTO.TESTEARRAY[]' to 'Relogio_Ponto.WS_FUNCSPONTO.TESTEARRAY

Answer (score 1):

É um problema simples de *cast*. Troque para o seguinte:

```
WS_FUNCSPONTO.TESTEARRAY[] qwert = new WS_FUNCSPONTO.TESTEARRAY[50];
```

Comment: Cigano, obrigado pela dica! Tentei como você sugeriu e o VS retornou o seguinte erro nessa linha: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Relogio_Ponto.WS_FUNCSPONTO.TESTEARRAY' to 'Relogio_Ponto.WS_FUNCSPONTO.TESTEARRAY[]'

Comment: Que estranho. O erro inverteu?

Comment: Consegui resolver! Era quase isso! Ficou assim: WS_FUNCSPONTO.TESTEARRAY[] qwert = new WS_FUNCSPONTO.TESTEARRAY[50];

Comment: @baltazar Vou adicionar seu comentário na resposta.